# Highcharts separating data by category

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I use highcharts to generate the graphs of a dinamic table that I generate with php + mysql and I would like to click on the category that it shows a graph with only the data of that category as it does with the columns

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  Highcharts.chart('chart', {
    data: {
      table: 'table_resultados'
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    yAxis: {
      allowDecimals: false,
      title: {
        text: ''
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
          this.point.y + ' ' + this.point.name;
      }
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_resultados" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead class="table-head">
    <tr>
      <th>Gravidade</th>
      <th class="nomes">SEGUNDA-FEIRA</th>
      <th class="nomes">TERÇA-FEIRA</th>
      <th class="nomes">QUARTA-FEIRA</th>
      <th class="nomes">QUINTA-FEIRA</th>
      <th class="nomes">SEXTA-FEIRA</th>
      <th class="nomes">SÁBADO</th>
      <th class="nomes">DOMINGO</th>
      <th class="nomes">Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>FATAL</td>
      <td class="SEGUNDA-FEIRA">7</td>
      <td class="TERÇA-FEIRA">5</td>
      <td class="QUARTA-FEIRA">6</td>
      <td class="QUINTA-FEIRA">9</td>
      <td class="SEXTA-FEIRA">5</td>
      <td class="SÁBADO">12</td>
      <td class="DOMINGO">8</td>
      <td class="Total">52</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>GRAVE</td>
      <td class="SEGUNDA-FEIRA">365</td>
      <td class="TERÇA-FEIRA">358</td>
      <td class="QUARTA-FEIRA">374</td>
      <td class="QUINTA-FEIRA">408</td>
      <td class="SEXTA-FEIRA">390</td>
      <td class="SÁBADO">529</td>
      <td class="DOMINGO">417</td>
      <td class="Total">2841</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>LEVE</td>
      <td class="SEGUNDA-FEIRA">441</td>
      <td class="TERÇA-FEIRA">443</td>
      <td class="QUARTA-FEIRA">451</td>
      <td class="QUINTA-FEIRA">483</td>
      <td class="SEXTA-FEIRA">512</td>
      <td class="SÁBADO">497</td>
      <td class="DOMINGO">435</td>
      <td class="Total">3262</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAO INFORMADO</td>
      <td class="SEGUNDA-FEIRA">190</td>
      <td class="TERÇA-FEIRA">210</td>
      <td class="QUARTA-FEIRA">208</td>
      <td class="QUINTA-FEIRA">217</td>
      <td class="SEXTA-FEIRA">220</td>
      <td class="SÁBADO">285</td>
      <td class="DOMINGO">240</td>
      <td class="Total">1570</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Totais">
      <td>TOTAL</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div id="chart" name="chart" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

[JSFIDDLE EXEMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kqgLjakj/)

In this example what I wanted to do is click on FATAL and show only the data for that category (table rows)

Comment: Actually Highcharts does not offer this feature out of the box - hiding/showing data based on categories. If you want to show/hide data according to some category you need to rebuild the whole series from scratch - and filter unwanted values. So, you need to set onclick event on a specific table-cell and filter the data with everything but the table cell's value. See example for fatal category - https://jsfiddle.net/fsm3pe8x/

Comment: @morganfree thks for your help
The problem is that I generate this table dynamically by PHP + MYSQL and when I post the event
$ (Document) .on ('click', '#FATAL', function () {
                chart.update({
                  series: chart.originalData.map(s => {
                    return {
                      name: s.name,
                      data: s.data.filter(p => p[0] === $(this).html())
                    }
                  })
                });
}
This error appears
Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: @morganfree look this
https://jsfiddle.net/fsm3pe8x/1/

Comment: In your onclick event, you do not have access to the chart variable - those are two seperates scopes. So you need to make the chart variable accessible, either by shifting var declaration or by accesing your chart from the global Highcharts.charts array. https://jsfiddle.net/fsm3pe8x/2/ https://jsfiddle.net/fsm3pe8x/3/

Comment: @morganfree Thanks, Thanks a lot, u save me...

Comment: @morganfree how i can reset chart to original data?

Comment: all unfiltered data is stored in chart.originalData - so all you need to do is set it as series https://jsfiddle.net/fsm3pe8x/4/ Just make sure that when you filter, set, etc. your series, you do not mutate originalData series.